# where are Android Chrome bookmarks?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android

What is the path of the bookmarks file for Chrome in Android 4.1.2? eg is it in the /sdcard/data directory or somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, they are stored under:

`data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/default/bookmarks`

Comment: unfortunately it appears that user must be `root` to get at that