# Where can I find the Chrome bookmarks stored locally in Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: chrome-for-android, bookmarks, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I'm freaking out as my Chrome browser on my rooted Samsung Galaxy S6 got reset after using Datasync, and when I opened my Chrome browser it showed as a fresh install. Like never used before.  I had months of research in my bookmarks which I now see did not get backed up.  Now would the bookmarks be stored locally on my S6 somewhere so I can access that info???

And I didn't sync my Chrome bookmarks to the cloud since before I kept losing bookmarks by synching across devices.

Comment: If you haven't synced your bookmarks in your mobile chrome but you have signed in with your gmail account you can find the website you visited in https://history.google.com/history/

Comment: @Lucky if i sign in through settings in Chrome is that syncing or just signing in? I get so confused.

Comment: @Lucky  Is there any way to get the history from june 2015 from the link you gave?  I see a download archive option ...what does that do?

Comment: You can't get your hands on them locally without root access. Chrome stores bookmarks in `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Bookmarks`. // It is a different matter if you end-up finding your old bookmarks or not, but that's the place to look for.

Comment: @Firelord   I AM rooted. ☺  How do I search?

Comment: Signing in to Chrome app and Syncing is two different things. You can signin and turn off syncing of chrome stuffs. Visit the history.google.com url and click see more link at the bottom of the page to visit to the particular date until you reach there.

Comment: Use [Root Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree) or [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) to visit "/ -> data -> data -> com.android.chrome -> app_chrome -> bookmarks".

Comment: @Firelord  I'm not too sure what EXACTLY to type to search..I type "data" then "data" ..?

Comment: It is the location you have to visit by first going to root directory (`/`) then go to `data` directory, then a `data` directory in it, and so on.

Comment: Did you get the file?

Comment: @Firelord Battery died! Have to try later. I'm to download search archives on my S3 but everytime I try to download and open nothing opens.

Comment: @Firelord  Is Root Browser or ES easier to use?

Comment: @Firelord   I downloaded  "ES File"  since it's maintained and opened it but unsure how to search still. How do I find the root directory?  The other issue is Google web history for Searches ask for my password every 5 min and then I have to start from the beginning to go back to the day of the month I was browsing.

Comment: You'll have to wait for few hours (not at home) to get proper screenshots for going into the Chrome Directory. You may try this until then: tap three horizontal lines at the top bar, go to Tools and enable Root Explorer. At the top bar, next to those lines, tap the entry and got /device -- the root directory. // That History part was suggested by a different user so I couldn't be of much help here other than to open the Google History page in new tab, and keep reloading it after 1-2 mins or so. You're probably observing session time-out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [where are Android Chrome bookmarks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39594/where-are-android-chrome-bookmarks)