# How do I get MyBackup Pro to back up Chrome bookmarks and not the stock browser?

Tags: bookmarks, samsung-galaxy-s-6

On my S6 I thought my Chrome bookmarks were being backup to the cloud using MyBackup Pro only to find it just backs up stock browser bookmarks.  Other backup apps in the Play store back up so many things like SMS etc. but how do I backup just the Chrome bookmarks locally or in the cloud?  Google's own sucks.

Comment: Just one single query: Does this MyBackup Pro needs root access or not? If not, then it can't backup Chrome bookmarks since they are located inside Chrome's data directory and an another app cannot access them unless it has quite high privileges, or an alternative and explicit way is available (I've never seen one). Even ADB would fail since Chrome for Android  disallows its backup. You'll have to rely on what I said [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116545/where-can-i-find-the-chrome-bookmarks-stored-locally-in-samsung-galaxy-s6?noredirect=1#comment145113_116545).

Comment: But the device is rooted, so why use MyBackup Pro when the champion of backups is [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)?

Comment: @Firelord  Seems to have bad reviews and bad interface. I remember looking into Titanium. Can it back up.Chrome  bookmarks?

Comment: It can backup the whole Chrome data, but not the bookmarks explicitly.

Comment: I tried this pro app, and I found that it doesn't give the option to backup any system app (which includes Chrome),  so you won't be able to backup your bookmarks using it. It's too bad because the app has root access. On a side note, don't go for the review on TitaniumBackup since it seems to be first choice amongst the users here. Plus, ask a question about it if you don't understand or has problem doing something in it (though many have been asked already here). I'm certain about my info about that Pro app. So, should I write my answer or you need something more?

Comment: Wait, I have something different to add now. I deleted my stock browser long time ago, so I've only Chrome and Firefox. When I backed up my bookmarks using that MyBackup Pro app, I found that Chrome bookmarks were actually backed up, and then restored well. So, if you don't use stock Browser, then simply disable it and then try this app.

Comment: So, did the comment work for you?