# Any way to get a text file list of all my Chrome Favourites?

Tags: chrome-for-android

How can I get a list of all my current Chrome favourites on my phone WITHOUT a PC. I need to do this without computer access at all. I'm on a S6 on 5.0.2.

Also, I only want to save the Favourites I saved in my Android browser. I don't Sync them online ever as the last time I did thousands of bookmarks just disappeared.  ☺

Comment: Didn't you ask this question earlier? [Where can I find the Chrome bookmarks stored locally in Samsung Galaxy S6?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/116545) `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Default/Bookmarks` is a plain text file.

Comment: @Firelord Nope, that was how to save them.

Comment: I can't file that file you are mentioning. Any easy way to find it?